# Sort list of integers and strings Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

i have to sort 3 objects that contains two integers and 1 string, my question is since I'm new to java, how can i call the object into the method, this is my code so far: So what I'm trying to do is to sort all 3 objects in increasing order, by age, name, general grade, how can i call all of them so i can sort ?, or if I'm doing it wrong, what the alternative? i need to use List and the 3 objects thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Student {

    int age;
    int generalGrade;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public Student(int age, String firstName, String lastName, int generalGrade) {
        this.age = age;
        this.generalGrade = generalGrade;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Student myStudent = new Student(19, "A", "X", 100);
        Student myStudent1 = new Student(20, "B", "P", 98);
        Student myStudent2 = new Student(19, "C", "N", 70);

        Age(myStudent);


    }

    public void Age(int[] age) {

        List studentAge = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(age));
        System.out.println("List values before sort " + studentAge);
        Collections.sort(studentAge);
        System.out.println("List value after sort: " + studentAge);
    }}
```

Comment: Write a custom Comparator and then Collections.sort using that comparator

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Comparable or Comparator interfaces. See this link about how to use them.
http://howtodoinjava.com/search-sort/when-to-use-comparable-and-comparator-interfaces-in-java/

Study above article and then try, and then ask questions here If you got any problem or doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with help of this guide: http://howtodoinjava.com/search-sort/when-to-use-comparable-and-comparator-interfaces-in-java/.

This is how my main looks like, and I have created 4 other classes that implements Compare

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Student student1 = new Student(19, "A", "X", 100);
        Student student2 = new Student(20, "B", "P", 98);
        Student student3 = new Student(19, "C", "N", 70);

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add(student1);
        students.add(student2);
        students.add(student3);

        Collections.sort(students);
        System.out.println("Sorted students " + students);

        System.out.println(" ");
        Collections.sort(students, new NameSort());
        System.out.println("Sort by name " + students );

        System.out.println(" ");
        Collections.sort(students, new AgeSort());
        System.out.println("Sort by age " + students);

        System.out.println(" ");
        Collections.sort(students, new SortGrade());
        System.out.println("Sort by General Grade " + students);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Decreasing order");
        System.out.println("");

        Collections.sort(students, Collections.reverseOrder(new NameSort()));
        System.out.println("Sort by name " + students );
        System.out.println("");
        Collections.sort(students, Collections.reverseOrder(new AgeSort()));
        System.out.println("Sort by age " + students );
        System.out.println("");
        Collections.sort(students, Collections.reverseOrder(new SortGrade()));
        System.out.println("Sort by General grade " + students );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to make your `Student` class a [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) implementation:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    // your code...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student student){
        // your sorting logic...
    }

}
```

This way `Collections.sort()` will use your logic to sort the list.

If your class can't implement `Comparable<T>`, then you can implement a custom [`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use this version of [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) method.